# Terminal Won't Work

Tags: command-line

My terminal doesn't even work. When ever I start it, the window does not show up. The tty terminals work.

[image]

Comment: Try to re-set the language settings system wide, you can access it through the top bar.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try Ctrl-Alt-T. This is the default keyboard shortcut to open a terminal in Ubuntu.

If the terminal does open, try running `gnome-terminal`. This should just duplicate the terminal you're currently running; it is the default terminal.

Additionally, you can try:

- Alt-F2. This allows you to run a command as if you are in a terminal. I recommend again attempting to run `gnome-terminal` or perhaps `xterm`.
- Right-click the "terminal" icon to remove from the Unity sidebar. Then, try to re-add it (perhaps after logging out and back in). If this fixed it, then that means that the sidebar link was somehow corrupted.